# Squid SslBump Peek and Slice leads to OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL for HTTPS connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, openssl, squid

I'm trying to setup DNS filtering using a transparent proxy using Squid v3.5 on AWS EC2. It works fine for HTTP traffic, but not for HTTPS traffic. For HTTPS traffic, I observe the following:

1. For websites not in the allow-list, I get an immediate `curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to google.com:443`
2. For websites in the allow-list, the connection hangs at the `TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):` state for a long time. Then finally throws a `curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to example.com:443`

**Squid Settings**

Squid version is `3.5.20` and compiled `--with-openssl` (I installed from yum and didn't compile myself). The full output of `squid -v` is shown below:

```
Squid Cache: Version 3.5.20
Service Name: squid
configure options:  '--build=x86_64-koji-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-koji-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--disable-strict-error-checking' '--exec_prefix=/usr' '--libexecdir=/usr/lib64/squid' '--localstatedir=/var' '--datadir=/usr/share/squid' '--sysconfdir=/etc/squid' '--with-logdir=$(localstatedir)/log/squid' '--with-pidfile=$(localstatedir)/run/squid.pid' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--enable-eui' '--enable-follow-x-forwarded-for' '--enable-auth' '--enable-auth-basic=DB,LDAP,MSNT-multi-domain,NCSA,NIS,PAM,POP3,RADIUS,SASL,SMB,SMB_LM,getpwnam' '--enable-auth-ntlm=smb_lm,fake' '--enable-auth-digest=file,LDAP,eDirectory' '--enable-auth-negotiate=kerberos' '--enable-external-acl-helpers=file_userip,LDAP_group,time_quota,session,unix_group,wbinfo_group,kerberos_ldap_group' '--enable-cache-digests' '--enable-cachemgr-hostname=localhost' '--enable-delay-pools' '--enable-epoll' '--enable-ident-lookups' '--enable-linux-netfilter' '--enable-removal-policies=heap,lru' '--enable-snmp' '--enable-ssl-crtd' '--enable-storeio=aufs,diskd,rock,ufs' '--enable-wccpv2' '--enable-esi' '--enable-ecap' '--with-aio' '--with-default-user=squid' '--with-dl' '--with-openssl' '--with-pthreads' '--disable-arch-native' 'build_alias=x86_64-koji-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-koji-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches    -m64 -mtune=generic -fpie' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro  -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches    -m64 -mtune=generic -fpie' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
```

`squid.conf` is shown below:

```
visible_hostname squid
cache deny all

# Log format and rotation
logformat squid %ts.%03tu %6tr %>a %Ss/%03>Hs %<st %rm %ru %ssl::>sni %Sh/%<a %mt
logfile_rotate 10
debug_options rotate=10

# Handle HTTP requests
http_port 3128
http_port 3129 intercept

# Handle HTTPS requests
https_port 3130 cert=/etc/squid/ssl/squid.pem ssl-bump intercept
acl SSL_port port 443
http_access allow SSL_port
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
acl step2 at_step SslBump2
acl step3 at_step SslBump3
ssl_bump peek step1 all

# Deny requests to proxy instance metadata
acl instance_metadata dst 169.254.169.254
http_access deny instance_metadata

# Filter HTTP requests based on the allowlist
acl allowed_http_sites dstdomain "/etc/squid/allowlist.txt"
http_access allow allowed_http_sites

# Filter HTTPS requests based on the allowlist
acl allowed_https_sites ssl::server_name "/etc/squid/allowlist.txt"
ssl_bump peek step2 allowed_https_sites
ssl_bump splice step3 allowed_https_sites
ssl_bump terminate step2 all

http_access deny all
```

iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3130
```

**AWS EC2/VPC Settings**

1. The squid proxy EC2 instance is in a public subnet
2. The squid proxy EC2 instance has source/destination check disabled
3. The client EC2 instance is in another public subnet
4. The security groups of these EC2 instances allow all inbound traffic internally (based on private IP) and allow all outbound traffic.

Route tables:

1. Routing for squid's subnet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY3MG.jpg
2. Routing for the client subnet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zkmq.jpg (the ENI ID is for the squid proxy's EC2)

Answer (score 0):

iptables rules as shown will match any http/https traffic on 80 and 443 ports, including connections squid initiates itself to target resources.

You need to add "! --uid-owner {squid uid}"  or "--uid-owner {initiator uid}" option to iptables command line, so it will match "not squid initiated connections" or "specific processes initiated connections identified by {initiator uid}" only.

So they should be as below:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp ! --uid-owner {squid uid} --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp ! --uid-owner {squid uid} --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3130
```

or

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --uid-owner {initiator uid} --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --uid-owner {initiator uid} --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3130
```

Comment: I have encountered similar problem, as in the OP. Have tried to use your commands but has got this output on debian11,EC2:
`root@squid:~# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp ! -m 13 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129`
`iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unexpected ! flag before --match`
`Try "iptables -h" or 'iptables --help' for more information`